# Allowing audio files with pronunciaton

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How possible would it be to allow uploading audio files for pronunciation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally agree with this suggestion.  Such functionality would be great, not only for RLE but also for all other language sites.  Interestingly, there was a request on the main meta.SO to add embedded audio player to `audio.SE` and `music.SE` sites - [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72365/can-an-embedded-audio-player-be-added-to-audio-se-and-music-se) - which now has [status-completed](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) on it. I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152282/embedded-audio-player-on-language-sites) on the main meta.SO site, requesting that this functionality be added to language sites.